# Don't remove "a" link on active page in CakePHP Pagination

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using CakePHP, and i need to paginate some stuff in my page.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap layout with CakePHP but unfortunaly, CakePHP paginates using the following logic:

If, the active link is equal to the active page, then it just removes the `a` tag from the link.

But, in order to my `Twitter Bootstrap layout` work, i need that `a` tag in all pagination numbers (including the active one): http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#pagination

Do i need to create a totaly new Helper to do this, or is there a 'simplest' solution?

I don't want to hack (change) twitter bootstrap and CakePHP core...

Thanks!

Ivan

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the user contributed [bootstrap plugins](http://plugins.cakephp.org/packages?query=bootstrap) to get more goodies besides desired pagination links. The ones by nodesagency and slywalker are recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend overriding the default PaginatorHelper. Basically, you create a new class like MyPaginatorHelper that extends PaginatorHelper, find the methods from the original helper that u need to modify, copy them from the original helper and modify them in your helper. The method you probably need to override is numbers(). So your class would look something like this:

```
<?php

class MyPaginatorHelper extends PaginatorHelper {

function numbers() {
...copy paste and modify...
}
```

Remember to us $this->MyPaginatorHelper in the view (and not the original one). This will not break anything, and *should* work even after updating the core without any changes necessary.